Orphaned EBS Volumes No Tags
We have numerous tagged and untagged EBS volumes that I am parsing from an excel spreadsheet. The volumes should have the tag: customer####. If the volumes don't have the tag, I manually use Cloudtrail to look up the associated instance-id of the volume. If there's no event in Cloudtrail with the ebs volume tag, I open aws config service and manually review the event history to find the customer tag in one of the events. My code returns the tagged ebs volumes but not the untagged volumes. I need to get the tags from the aws config event history for each ID, but how is this part of the code created?
import boto3 
import pprint
import csv
from openpyxl import load_workbook
AWS_REGION = "us-gov-west-1"
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name = AWS_REGION)

wb = load_workbook("list.xlsx")  
ws = wb['sheet1']  
column = ws['D']  
column_list = [column[x].value for x in range(len(column))]  

volumes_string =" ".join(map(str,column_list)).split(",")

for volume in ec2.volumes.filter(
    Filters=[
        {
            'Name': 'status',
            'Values': [
                'available',
            ]
        },
        {
            'Name': 'tag:Instance',
            'Values': [
                '*',
            ]
        },
    ]
):
    pprint.pp(f'Volume {volume.id} ({volume.size} GiB) state is {volume.state} {volume.tags}')

Returns
("Volume vol-0bfeae0c4199189c4 (100 GiB) state is available [{'Key': "
 "'Customer', 'Value': 'customer0038'}, {'Key': 'Instance', 'Value': "
 "'i-07c82bb0d817a2e00'}, {'Key': 'Hostname', 'Value': 'ns2pd1app1'}]")
("Volume vol-098ff9f7c42d8d4d7 (50 GiB) state is available [{'Key': "
 "'Instance', 'Value': 'i-00f6dce11b5c18dd2'}, {'Key': 'MountPoint', 'Value': "
 "'/usr/sap'}, {'Key': 'Name', 'Value': "
 "'783bff3ae6a05ff085f4e425a62a55ae_usr_sap'}, {'Key': 'Customer', 'Value': "
 "'customer0038'}, {'Key': 'Hostname', 'Value': 'ns2pd2app1'}]")
("Volume vol-0de9b26007036fcff (32 GiB) state is available [{'Key': "
 "'MountPoint', 'Value': '/swap'}, {'Key': 'Hostname', 'Value': 'ns2pd2app1'}, "
 "{'Key': 'Customer', 'Value': 'customer0038'}, {'Key': 'Instance', 'Value': "
 "'i-00f6dce11b5c18dd2'}, {'Key': 'Name', 'Value': "
 "'5a91387904285496a90641f8f0669562_swap'}]")
("Volume vol-0a09e242faaf7a218 (32 GiB) state is available [{'Key': "
 "'MountPoint', 'Value': '/swap'}, {'Key': 'Name', 'Value': "
 "'ce3210dd1f3b508786bb4010ed797424_swap'}, {'Key': 'Instance', 'Value': "
 "'i-07c82bb0d817a2e00'}, {'Key': 'Hostname', 'Value': 'ns2pd1app1'}, {'Key': "
 "'Customer', 'Value': 'customer0038'}]")
("Volume vol-051236bb8df2b2c77 (100 GiB) state is available [{'Key': "
 "'Customer', 'Value': 'customer0038'}, {'Key': 'Hostname', 'Value': "
 "'ns2pd2app1'}, {'Key': 'Instance', 'Value': 'i-00f6dce11b5c18dd2'}]")
("Volume vol-0ceb490a67c78d041 (50 GiB) state is available [{'Key': "
 "'MountPoint', 'Value': '/usr/sap'}, {'Key': 'Hostname', 'Value': "
 "'ns2pd1app1'}, {'Key': 'Instance', 'Value': 'i-07c82bb0d817a2e00'}, {'Key': "
 "'Name', 'Value': '7e03c294981e58e0ab803778fe62d825_usr_sap'}, {'Key': "
 "'Customer', 'Value': 'customer0038'}]")
("Volume vol-0462fb9f9efa2c9bc (100 GiB) state is available [{'Key': "
 "'Customer', 'Value': 'customer0038'}, {'Key': 'Instance', 'Value': "
 "'i-0e8f3ca62869c43f9'}, {'Key': 'Hostname', 'Value': 'ns2ws4app1'}]")
("Volume vol-0e6a5cb390f52dc7c (50 GiB) state is available [{'Key': "
 "'Customer', 'Value': 'customer0038'}, {'Key': 'Instance', 'Value': "
 "'i-0e8f3ca62869c43f9'}, {'Key': 'MountPoint', 'Value': '/usr/sap'}, {'Key': "
 "'Name', 'Value': '9cb8744ca3f956db9b1dbffec477a1a8_usr_sap'}, {'Key': "
 "'Hostname', 'Value': 'ns2ws4app1'}]")
("Volume vol-069441ba154989a32 (50 GiB) state is available [{'Key': 'Name', "
 "'Value': '9cb8744ca3f956db9b1dbffec477a1a8_sapmnt'}, {'Key': 'Customer', "
 "'Value': 'customer0038'}, {'Key': 'Hostname', 'Value': 'ns2ws4app1'}, "
 "{'Key': 'Instance', 'Value': 'i-0e8f3ca62869c43f9'}, {'Key': 'MountPoint', "
 "'Value': '/sapmnt'}]")
['Volume Id vol-0bfeae0c4199189c4 vol-051236bb8df2b2c77 vol-0ceb490a67c78d041 '
 'vol-098ff9f7c42d8d4d7 vol-0de9b26007036fcff vol-0a09e242faaf7a218 '
 'vol-0462fb9f9efa2c9bc vol-0e6a5cb390f52dc7c vol-069441ba154989a32 '
 'vol-09243ea296b2e2ea9 vol-090fa2f0d7a2e4c9e vol-0952992367815c933 '
 'vol-04107b4992cbba59d vol-00a12275501f5a704 vol-0edc6022d95669594 '
 'vol-0269c439ed1309fa8 vol-060794431cdabf640 vol-036a9dd9e30036706 '
 'vol-0d63835780b5d25cd vol-000e80908d5b485b2 vol-0e1c14e0390533980 '
 'vol-0877d34c8b8ecdab3 vol-0e11fd5d78ca09392 vol-06443e22755acf14f '
 'vol-04e4cd65eee610ec3 vol-0d0faed3f8b584a69 vol-090fca66cfb176c45 '
 'vol-051828390f1dbfc95 vol-0402446d9eb534919 vol-009ea6f32f4279e91 '
 'vol-080e23091ac57d34f vol-0987044109b004c74 vol-0566138f1676200ca '
 'vol-0bcdb1247d6961d14 vol-07eeecde0e9d416d7 vol-07c8e7ed59d8d9975 '
 'vol-0463f9440835a32cc vol-04b59906063176665 vol-02c224d0f9b52ff6c '
 'vol-016d3df3f72836ed7 vol-00bea50077a9696d1 vol-0c89de3a6593b8a68 '
 'vol-0ac2867efedaefcb6 vol-0d361c1261c4f27ff vol-0cdca89b5e4fbf564 '
 'vol-0d451b522873f21fb vol-00bcb3abf240932a7 vol-0d8f4f9ac4fa7c22e '
 'vol-006e165e828d5ce78 vol-0f096af93dd9ab3fd vol-093cf818c1f23351b '
 'vol-0eb3f73adead83d2f vol-0939ebda6810651c8 vol-00adbdc9832794159 '
 'vol-047f3aa366a4061d9 vol-095ec7cde79e56fe5 vol-029aba4e53df151ab '
 'vol-0f934ff033d8308ac vol-034b1dff5f987b0b0 vol-061bb9841c7caf411 '
 'vol-0d15ffe2a5664d2d7 vol-0348dee3141302fce vol-0e60fa14498f27df7 '
 'vol-04119933844c70631 vol-01f22e4d48748efd2 vol-095a6ac62ee4cb49e '
 'vol-0aba4593b41024d9c vol-04a2c69babffc954c vol-033f56cfa3d11dc34 '
 'vol-029aeb34aef2e9c28 vol-0010a8f692f4cb0fc vol-015ebd67a7975af46 '
 'vol-03a04997d05e211cf vol-0ddfde85ff5b8eed7 vol-0b8545223aa56995f '
 'vol-00cb17258abca23d7 vol-056f8e526a8336008 vol-0443a78bc97ab5824 '
 'vol-0cbc9aea69b2c4f07 vol-0a4a670b53f8c69a8 vol-026460dd26ebcae4c '
 'vol-0f9553267a778e2ac vol-09c482d5f4027520a vol-0aa0925f83affc592 '
 'vol-00709bba378de09c5 vol-0ac405c5c116a4d00 vol-05cb8d5b9412747c1 '
 'vol-010a41c205a5f53f8 vol-0a04cb695b37e8be2 vol-0311a6eda07df38d9 '
 'vol-004b915523fe9d95f vol-06491a4ecee6c1702 vol-0090fac3dbe6f35d5 '
 'vol-0136b40d4eba96b55 vol-0d85fc30ab9ea544d vol-0a7cfe562c68a4053 '
 'vol-0b8cbfb6467c5b361 vol-085c49b92c62188dd vol-03c29cb7a581881d5 '
 'vol-08f92102d6881c617 vol-0eb83c824e731eef4 vol-01d8941a0f23fde8c '
 'vol-05e6d131ae68b23af vol-0a4c1a4ff23345f60 vol-0001f2802eca10319 '
 'vol-0773f2c01258ffcb1 vol-040cf8642647c732e vol-026951e39ee4129c9 '
 'vol-0c9a4807978486a09 vol-0cd75e222285bfcf5 vol-001c547ab9807faed '
 'vol-0cdd5b2e914ada13b vol-0f3f0b37f6a87b80d vol-04465c5ce0611e8a3 '
 'vol-03dea102f60c63dcc vol-0d3c8447722a81a2b vol-088ceb859d703b3ae '
 'vol-06929a3a4f173ca17 vol-02134b21103d94221 vol-0b33033e0eabae35d '
 'vol-0210c26ceea5d17be vol-06db8d4428ee06b12 vol-0a50ff4c6e4afe2cd '
 'vol-094089ed35898848a vol-0a5a56ae7f7149009 vol-03f3d5d993ff20349 '
 'vol-09712a07548da2a02 vol-094174e6a2a8455a1 vol-08dc9505042e65f3f '
 'vol-0808ffb43796ab8f3 vol-09dc1aedf1cbe3ff0 vol-00bec85e423f0c2c2 '
 'vol-07fa7a94be8ff0ce5 vol-0dbefaede503ed89e vol-0b07eb851e2e67c24 '
 'vol-0806347be6c81a9de vol-0285f666a01029c84 vol-071d4d3b04937da00']


Sorry, but could you please clarify your question? Are you asking how to filter for volumes without tags? It would probably be easiest to remove the Tag filter, and then use Python to filter the list based on the returned values.
